How to add a property with the count of a join to my jpa entity
I have a jpa entity like this:
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
  class CustomerEntity(
    id: Long = 0,
    ...,
    countOfRelatedTable: int = this is the property I want to add
  )
}

my repo looks like this:
interface AbstractCustomerRepository: JpaRepository<AbstractCustomerEntity, Long> {
    fun findAllByDeletedFalse(): List<AbstractCustomerEntity>
}

I have a table that has a relationship with customer via several joins. I just want to have the number / count of results. How can I add and populate this property to the entity?
